# Zuul gateway return code 200 response when failed

Tags: netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

When happens something like: `UnknownHostException`

```
com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Filter threw Exception
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:227)
.............................
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.net.UnknownHostException cannot be cast to com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.post.SendErrorFilter.findZuulException(SendErrorFilter.java:104)
```

or by timeout: `SocketTimeoutException`

```
com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Filter threw Exception
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:227)
.............................
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException cannot be cast to com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.post.SendErrorFilter.findZuulException(SendErrorFilter.java:104)
```

the gateway return successful status code 200...

it's normal begavior?

it's can be tuned?

or maybe I must catch it and throw custom error if code 200 not acceptable for me?

Answer (score 0):

its was a bug in old version, update to latest release fixed it